# the folder session cannot be handled because you do not hava permission to read it in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

i'm trying to delete the folder it showing the above error in ubuntu

Comment: Try it with `sudo` or change the permissions

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
sudo chmod -R 777 foldername 
or 
sudo chmod -R 777 filename
```

if you give permission to all folder or all file then

```
sudo chmod -R 777 *
```